# Some widget of a Flutter app not updated after changing locale

Tags: flutter, localization, state

I'm using `easy_localization` to localize my app, and I'm listening for `WidgetsBindingObserver.didChangeLocales` to see if user change its device/per-app locale to correctly update my app language.

It works with some widgets, they do use the new language, but not all, some have not been rebuilt to display the new language.

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/MrSquaare/47dcd34bae74505c194cfc526884421f

In this code, `MyRootNavigationPage` is correctly updated but neither `MyHomePage` nor `MySettingsPage` are.

I suspect this is a state issue, but I don't really know where to start to debug the problem.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: please add some code the widget that is not rebuilding, as I know you only have to change the local on the main material app and all the strings will be rebuilt without any additional functions

Comment: @RamiAlDebs I've added a link to the code to the post